# Group of buttons rendered from list are not being re-rendered on click and their value returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a difficulties setting where you can choose the difficulty from 4 options laid out in a group of buttons, I also want to put a border on the selected button and have the difficulty change on click, getting the difficulty from the value of the button. The problem is that the button isn't changing on click and the value of it becomes undefined for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { config } from "../config";

const difficulties: Difficulty[] = ["Easy", "Normal", "Hard", "Extreme"]

export default function DifficultySettingsComponent() {
  const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(config.difficulty)

  function changeDificulty(event: any) {
    setDifficulty(event.target.value)
    config.difficulty = difficulty
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="font-bold text-lg">Difficulty:</h2>
      <div className=" space-x-2 m-3">
        {difficulties.map((difficulty) => (
          <button className=" bg-zinc-400 px-3 py-2 border-black rounded-md"
            key={difficulty}
            onClick={changeDificulty}
            value={difficulty}
            style={{ borderWidth: difficulty == config.difficulty ? 2 : 0 }}
          >
            <p className="font-bold">{difficulty}</p>
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: difficulty settings menu]

If anyone could tell me how to correctly update the buttons I would really apreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the button to an `input type="button` based on @Willow's answer and it now correctcly takes the `value`. I also had to change the if statement for the border and it worked, here's my new working code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { config } from "../config";

const difficulties: Difficulty[] = ["Easy", "Normal", "Hard", "Extreme"]

export default function DifficultySettingsComponent() {
  const [currentDifficulty, setCurrentDifficulty] = useState(config.difficulty)

  function changeDificulty(event: any) {
    setCurrentDifficulty(event.target.value)
    config.difficulty = currentDifficulty
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="font-bold text-lg">Difficulty:</h2>
      <div className=" space-x-2 m-3">
        {difficulties.map((difficulty) => (
          <input className=" bg-zinc-400 px-3 py-2 border-black rounded-md"
            type="button"
            key={difficulty}
            onClick={changeDificulty}
            value={difficulty}
            style={{ borderWidth: difficulty == currentDifficulty ? 2 : 0 }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using your `button` as though it was an `input type="radio"`. The `value` of a button doesn't do what you're expecting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

In this scenario, you should probably aim to use radio buttons that are styled to look like buttons. It will be more in line with a regular form that way. For example, if you're using Bootstrap, you can use "Toggle Buttons" https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#toggle-buttons

Hopefully this gives you a place to start!

Comment: Thanks @Willow, altho I didn't have to use an input type radio I was able to make it work using an input type button thanks to your answer :)

Comment: No problem! I would still recommend using radio buttons though, because it will make your form more accessible to people using assistive devices. Using the "correct" element in HTML forms is an important part of web accessibility, because it gives users information about what the function of the elements are. So with any kind of "toggle" like this, you should really be trying to use a radio button, and handle any styling with CSS.